# How to include twig within twig

Tags: php, twig

I need help in including in a twig file, another twig file

For example, I have:
_cdn/widgets/filter/filter.php
_cdn/widgets/filter/view/filter.twig

And:
themes/tema02/view/search.twig
themes/tema02/search.php

I need to include the filter.twig in the search.twig
But when I use include, it does not render the filter.php
And it gets a lot of 'Undefined variable:'

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First  of  all  show your code . It's always  easier to give right  anwser  when you see the code.

Use  `{% include %}`   for including  twig in twig

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html

Based on your description  you need to pass requred variables  to included twig , something like this

```
{% include 'filter.twig' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

OR

In filter twig  you can put  if ... is defined  where you try to access variable

```
{% if foo is defined %}   
    code where you doing something  with  foo variable 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: but variables are all in filter.php, is it just a filter.php require in search.php?

Comment: if you have "Undefined variable"  error - that  means than  some variable is not passed  to filter.twig